# Accessing Knockout Component ViewModel from CustomBinding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to create a custom Knockout component to wrap around a Google Chart's graph (or any chart library for that matter).

Ideally I would like to make a component with a viewmodel that holds the graph data. Once that component is bound using a custom binding, whenever the update function is called I would access that array with the data, add the new value, and tell the graph to redraw.

The problem is when I am inside the update function of the bindinghandler, I cannot see the graph's view model. How can I access this?

Component:

```
        ko.components.register('line-graph', {
        viewModel: function(params) {
            var self = this;
            self.data = new google.visualization.DataTable(
            {
                cols: [{id: 'index', label: '', type: 'number'},
                       {id: 'value', label: '', type: 'number'}]

            }, 0.6);
            self.currentPoint = 1;
            self.lastValue = null;
        },
        template:
            '<div></div>'
        });
```

Binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.lineGraph = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
         var observable = valueAccessor();

         if(observable != null){
             //Here, the viewmodel and all properties of the bindingContext correspond to the main viewmodel, not the graph's viewmodel
             viewModel.data.addRow([viewModel.currentPoint++, value]);
             drawChart();
         }

         viewModel.lastValue = value;
    }
}
```

Update: Here is how I plan to use the binding. The pressureValue variable would be a value in my main viewmodel that is being updated constantly in the background.

```
<line-graph data-bind="lineGraph: pressureValue"></line-graph>
```

Any thoughts? Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: A component isn't a binding, is your template value missing some data binding in the example above,  as well as `var self=this;` ?  Can you also show the HTML where the knockout component is being used ?

Comment: I added my planned usage to the post, I also seem to have missed copying the var self = this;. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are combining two different concepts here.

When using the new component feature of Knockout the data-bind syntax is different

refer to : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html

```
<line-graph params="value: pressureValue"></line-graph>
```

or

```
<div data-bind="component: {name: 'line-graph', params: {value: pressureValue}}"></div>
```

Knockout will invoke your component and replace the contents of your custom element with the DOM you supply from the template value.  In your case, the template is an empty DIV with no data-bind.  At no point is your custom binding invoked.

Your component should now have the pressureValue observable sent into the viewModel function as the params argument.

I think, based on what your custom binding is expected, you need to add this "value" to the viewModel

```
viewModel: function(params) {
    ...
    self.value = params.value;
}
```

Your template of the component should now become ( where $data is the value of the object returned from the viewModel function of the component )

```
template: '<div data-bind="lineGraph: $data.value"><div>'
```

This should now fire your custom binding and, hopefully, get the result you expect.

I think there is still something missing from your samples above as the variable `value` in your update binding is declared anywhere, should that have been `observable`.  A bit of tweaking will be required but the basic data flow above should be what you need.

Please let me know if I'm on the right track...

Comment: You are definitely on the right track. With your addition I have the right viewModel and I get the update handler. One issue I am having is that the update fires twice. The first time it is undefined, the second time it is the correct value. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what I was doing wrong, but I re-implemented your solution and it seems to be working fine now. I believe I was using <line-graph VALUE=... instead of <line-graph params=... 

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use ko.dataFor(element) or ko.contextFor(element) from inside the update function to get the ViewModel.

See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html for documentation and an example.

Edit: Turns out this doesn't work if you put the binding directly on the component. For the proper solution see Robert Slaney's answer.

Comment: Both of those variables have the main viewmodel in them, not my components. Is there something that I am not doing to setup the viewmodel for the component?